# Generate access token without code challenge and code verifier, with django rest along django-oauth-toolkit for OAuth access

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, oauth

I am trying to generate the `access_token` and `refresh_token` with Django rest framework and django-oauth-toolkit lib for the OAuth access delegation. I am trying to delegate the access to third party platform, where the third-party platform display the login button and when a user clicks the button it will open my website with `response_type`, `client_id`, `scope`, and `redirect_uri`. (all of these variable will be set on the third-party platform while setup).

As per the django-oauth-toolkit documentation we also need to pass the `code_challenge` and `code_challenge_method` in the url while opening the login link, but third-party platform does not pass these 2 variables in the request.

As per [this](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html?highlight=PKCE#pkce-required) documentations I am tryed by setting the `PKCE_REQUIRED=False` in the setting file of the project but getting an error of `code_challenge` in the response.

Request URL
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/authorize/?response_type=code&client_id=bG2Ju69XwS8jvnx3CWiobmWi1dj4kWsNYSiVsXEa&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/code/redirect/`

Response
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/code/redirect/?error=invalid_request&error_description=Code+challenge+required.`

The authentication functionality is working with the `code_challenge` in the URL and able to generate the `authorization_code`

Working example

Request URL
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/authorize/?response_type=code&client_id=bG2Ju69XwS8jvnx3CWiobmWi1dj4kWsNYSiVsXEa&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/code/redirect/&code_challenge=yCo4U9wZJPeYGyX3F6df_heuxG-6ZnvZfZB5KrCYpp4&code_challenge_method=S256`

Response
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/code/redirect/?code=EAwEXghF807RTjxwyohky8psQKGohP`

I also tried with the `OAUTH2_USE_PKCE = False` in the setting file but not working.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by setting the variable in the OAUTH2_PROVIDER dict instead of setting it directly in the setting file.

```
...

OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': 3600,
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': 3600 * 24 * 365,
    'PKCE_REQUIRED': False,
}

# PKCE_REQUIRED=False

...
```